# Previous / Next Links do not work on first and last records in model (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my model:

```
def next
  self.class.find(:first,
    :conditions => ['id > ?', self.id], 
   :order => 'id')

end 
def previous
  self.class.find(:first,
    :conditions => ['id < ?', self.id],
   :order => 'id desc')
end
```

and the code on the show page:

```
   <button align="center" type="button" class="btn btn- btn-xs">
            <%= link_to("Previous Image", pin_url(@pin.next))%>  </button>

   <button align="center" type="button" class="btn btn- btn-xs">
            <%= link_to("Next Image", pin_url(@pin.previous)) %> </button> </P>
```

This works great unless you are on the first or last record in the DB. And I am getting this error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pins", :id=>nil}

How can I avoid this error when users are navigating on the first and last record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your helper method to

```
def next_image
  self.class.where('id > ?', self.id).order('id asc').first
end
def previous
  self.class.where('id < ?', self.id).order('id desc').first
end
```

And then in view:

```
<% prev = @pin.previous %>
<% next_image = @pin.next_image %>  
<%= link_to 'Previous image', pin_url(prev) if prev.present? %>
<%= link_to 'Next image', pin_url(next_image) if next_image.present? %>
```

Comment: Would the next model look the same?

Comment: Yes, just change `<` to `>`

Comment: so like this :def next
  self.class.where('id < ?', self.id).order('id desc').first
end

Comment: would you be able to post the helper method and view code for next ?

Comment: awesome, this is a lifesaver

Comment: just check a condition for next `if self.id == self.class.last.id self.class.first else self.class.where('id > ?', self.id).order('id asc').first end` same for prev      `if self.id == self.first.id self.class.last else self.class.where('id < ?', self.id).order('id desc').first end `

Comment: actually I am getting an error...there is something about this "next" call it doesnt like

Comment: the next is showing in a bad color in the code  and the page does not load

Comment: Maybe, Ruby take `next` as keyword, not as method. Try another name, I've update my answer again.